# Camel servicall not resolving host and port as expected

Tags: java, apache-camel, hystrix

Hi I am new to using camel..I face two issues here:

1) I have implemented 2 serviceCalls in one camel route. My understanding of serviceCall is that it will resolve the host and port of the VIP (I'm trying to resolve the Eureka VIP for my AWS instance) that is given and the result is set to the headers CamelServiceCallServiceHost and CamelServiceCallServicePort.

My route looks something like below:

```
     from(fromUri).routeId("routeid").description(
                   "This route takes SQS message")
           .unmarshal()
                   .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, SQSMessage.class).process(sqsMessageProcessor)
                   .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, 
            constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET))

                   // 1st Service call
                   .setBody().constant(null).setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
           .hystrix().hystrixConfiguration().executionTimeoutInMilliseconds(hystrixTimeout).end()
                   .serviceCall().name("the Eureka VIP of the 1st call").expression()
                   .simple("http4:${header.CamelServiceCallServiceHost}:${header.CamelServiceCallServicePort}"
                           + "< -- the path and parameters for the call goes here --->")
                   .end() 
                   .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, ResponseClass1.class)
                   .process(FirstServiceCallProcessor)

           // 2nd Service call
                   .setBody().constant(null)
           .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
                   .serviceCall().name("the Eureka VIP of the 2nd call").expression()
                   .simple("http4:${header.CamelServiceCallServiceHost}:${header.CamelServiceCallServicePort}"
                           + "< -- the path and parameters for the call goes here --->")
                   .end() 
                   .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, ResponseClass2.class)
                   .process(SecondServiceCallProcessor)
```

My issue is that, my 1st service call works fine and i am getting the expected response. But while the second service call is executed i found that the resolved host and port is the same as the previous service call. My understanding is that the second serviceCall was not successfully executed and the headers were taken from the values set in the 1st service call.

Why is this so.

I would also be nice if someone could provide some insight on how the serviceCall resolves the host and port.

2) I have also implemented hystrix in my route (as you can see in the code). What i have noticed is that when i use hystrix, and if there is an error or failure anywhere in the route after that, i don't get any exception logs. Why is the exception not logged. I got to know that the 2nd service call is not working properly by removing the hystrix implementation. Only after that could i see the logs for the exception thrown.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? I think we had a bug around using expressions on the serviceCall EIP that was only recently fixed in one of the latest releases

Comment: I am using version 2.20.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we recently found out the issue.

before doing the second service call you have to remove the headers set by camel service  call. These can be found in the interface 'ServiceCallConstants'

The below example shows how to remove all headers related to service call. this should be done before the 2nd service call is made:

```
from("routeId").removeHeaders("CamelServiceCall*").end();
```